# Unable to edit database table in jsf

Tags: mysql, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I have another problem on my project I am working right now, I have searched everywhere to find some solution for this but couldn't get...

I'm having a bean class with id,firstName,lastName attributes having public getters and setters, and an updateEmployee method.

i'm using following jsf page to get database table values.

When i click on update button success page is shown but values are not changing in the database. Can any one tell me the reason that why vales are not getting change in the database?

JSF page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{tableBean.employeeList}" var="employee" border="1">  
   <h:column>  
          <f:facet name="header">First name</f:facet>  
          <h:inputText value="#{employee.firstName}" />  
   </h:column>  

   <h:column>  
          <f:facet name="header">Last name</f:facet>  
          <h:inputText value="#{employee.lastName}" />  
   </h:column>  
</h:dataTable>  
<h:commandButton value = "update" action="#{employee.updateEmployee}"/>
```

Employee.java:

```
public String updateEmployee(){  
   String query = "update employee set firstName = ?,lastName = ? where id = 1";           
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);  
   pstmt.setString(2,this.firstName);  
   pstmt.setString(3,this.lastName);   
   pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement  
   conn.commit();  
   committed = true;  
   return "success.xhtml";  
   }catch (Exception e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
       return null;  
   } finally {  
      try{  
         if (!committed) conn.rollback();  
              pstmt.close();  
          conn.close();  
       }catch(Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
      }  
    }  
 }
```

Thanks,
Raam

Comment: What is the scope of the bean?

Comment: Hi, Its session scoped..

Comment: The posted code only updates employee with id = 1

Comment: yah, just wanted to test with one of them first but its not updating it.. ):

Comment: database still showing the same values for ID 1..

Comment: I figured that was the case, but wanted to double check.  Also, indexes in prepared statement look wrong.  (2 and 3 instead of 1 and 2)

Comment: I have tried 1 and 2 still the same case..

Comment: Is the datatable enclosed in a form?

Answer (score 1):

The posted code is strange. You're not invoking the action method on the bean holding all edited employees, but you're instead invoking the action method on the bean which represents by itself a completely blank instance of an employee, which is not one of the employees shown in the table.

To start, replace

```html
<h:commandButton value="update" action="#{employee.updateEmployee}" />
```

by

```html
<h:commandButton value="update" action="#{tableBean.updateEmployees}" />
```

and it'll become more straightforward.